# Anyone Know of Any Homebrewing Video Tutorial Blogs

Tags: beer, bottling, mash, ingredients, wort

Does anyone know of a good homebrewing blog that has video tutorials?
I've Googled it and found a bunch of video tutorial blogs, but they're not great.
Anyone know of some good ones?

Comment: What information are you looking for?  There are lots of homebrewing channels on Youtube (e.g. [Northern Brewer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCh_h4W2VmFdo3R8g1XaXN_Q)).

Comment: I'm new to homebrewing.  It's all very intimidating.  If you do this, then you need to do that.  Every recipe has so many variables.  Everyone I ask for help can't seem to give me exact ways to do a recipe.I tried 1 recipe but half the bottles were over carbonated.  I'm looking for a good video blog that shows exactly how to do it.  I know if I can do a few successful batches, I'll start to get it.

Comment: Ignoring the carbonation problems, how did the beer taste?  Were there any flavors that were obviously wrong?  Obviously, the carbonation being out of whack is going to affect the flavor, but it should still taste something like beer.  If it does, that means that your process is "close enough", and fixing your carbonation problem (as discussed in your other thread) should get you some tasty beer.  If you're still looking for a video to watch to affirm that what you're doing is right,[Northern Brewer's Homebrewing 101 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaDQ6S6p6Wk) is pretty good.

Comment: Search for Homebrew Wednesday on Youtube. There's a whole community attached to it called Brewtubers

Answer (score 1):

have you checked out YouTube?  There are thousands of them.. some good.. some not so good.

Comment: Can you give a few channels that are Good?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said already youtube has  a mass of informative videos but filtering them can be tricky. Herb Tarlek is right Northern Brewer is a good place to start and this video in particular is a good starter:

Northern brewer Starter 101: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaDQ6S6p6Wk

For more general brewing information and tutorials:

Beer Geek Nation: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpACreb1E23Z3anMUkHi0qg

Northern Brewer: https://www.youtube.com/user/NorthernBrewerTV

There are some good podacsts out there:

Brew Bubba's: http://www.brewbubbas.com/site/brew_bubbas_radio/brew_bubbas_radio.html

Basic Brewing Radio: 
http://www.basicbrewing.com/index.php?page=radio

Comment: Thanks fellas.  This was exactly what I was hoping for.  I've spent some serious time surfing Youtube, but there are a lot of terrible videos out there and I find myself just wasting time.
This works!

Answer (score 0):

Herb Tarlek is right... there are tons of youTube channels and Northern Brewer's stuff is good.  As to the matter of overcarbing some bottles and undercarbing others in the same batch: here's how to solve that... take 2 cups of water and add your priming sugar to it.  Bring it to a boil and hold it there until the sugar is fully dissolved.  Pour that into your bottling bucket.  Rack your beer on top of it.  Bottle your beer.  Wait 2 weeks.  Easy Peasy. Do NOT use those sugar drops or try measuring out the right amount of priming sugar in each bottle.